# greedy character matching at end of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I'm trying to match the following string:

`controller1/action1/something`

With the following regex:

`(?P<controller>[[:alnum:]]+)/(?P<action>[[:alnum:]]+)/(.*)`

For some reason it doesn't find the last part of the string: `something`. But it works when i change the `*` to `+` at the end of the regex:

`(?P<controller>[[:alnum:]]+)/(?P<action>[[:alnum:]]+)/(.+)`

With that regex it does find the `something` string. But i want to use `.*` (or `.*?`) because i want this regex to succeed also when it doesn't have something at the end.

So it should also succeed when the string is: `controller1/action1/`

So why doesn't it work with `(.*)` or `(.*?)` but works with `.+`? The difference should simply be that the first says "zero or more characters" and the last "one or more". I simply want to check for "zero or more".

PS. I don't want to use `^` and `$` to denote the beginning and end of the string due to a complexer problem. Simply stated, this pattern doesn't always occur for strings at the end.

Comment: Looks like it works to me: [Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kTVfFXXl_4cva7Jo)

Comment: It works for me too, [Another Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qG7sG5).

Comment: Maybe post your PHP code, and an example of a full input string you're testing against

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `So it should also succeed when the string is: controller1/action1/`

I suspect since this input is part of some bigger string that's why `.*` isn't working for you. suggest you to post some real examples of your input text.

Meanwhile can you try this regex:

```
"#(?P<controller>[^/]+)/(?P<action>[^/]+)/([^/]*)#"
```

Comment: I thought he/she specifically asked for a solution without `^` and `$`

Comment: The example that i gave is exactly what i'm using in my test. But your regex seems to be working fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make the last group optional to make it match `controller1/action1/`

```
(?P<controller>[[:alnum:]]+)/(?P<action>[[:alnum:]]+)/(.+)?
```